# How can I show that $O( \sqrt{n} \cdot \log_2(n) \cdot \log_2(\log_2(n))) < O(n)$?

Tags: inequality, computational-complexity

The question is pretty straightforward: How can I show that

$$O( \sqrt{n} \cdot \log_2(n) \cdot \log_2(\log_2(n))) < O(n)$$

---

The question can be reduced by observing that $O(n) = O(\sqrt{n}) \cdot O(\sqrt{n})$.

Then we want to show that

$$O( \sqrt{n} \cdot \log_2(n) \cdot \log_2(\log_2(n))) < O(\sqrt{n}) \cdot O(\sqrt{n})$$

$$ \require{cancel} \cancel{O( \sqrt{n})}  \cdot O(\log_2(n) \cdot \log_2(\log_2(n))) < O(\sqrt{n}) \cdot \cancel{O(\sqrt{n})}$$

So what is left is to prove that $$ O(\log_2(n) \cdot \log_2(\log_2(n))) < O(\sqrt{n})$$

But since I cannot find a relation between $\log_2(n)$ and $\sqrt{n}$, I couldn't prove it yet.

Comment: Show that $\frac{\log_2(n) \log_2(\log_2(n))}{\sqrt{n}}$ is bounded.

Comment: How can I show that? I don't even know what the bound is. Do I need to find the bounds using the derivative of this function and then prove that it is impossible for this function to go over the bounds?

Comment: It's not only bounded, but in fact that ratio tends to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n} (\log n) (\log \log n)} = \infty$, by applying L'Hospital's rule twice.